# What's the meaning of `weightLimit: Unlimited` in `BuyExecution`?

Tags: xcm

What's the meaning of `weightLimit: Unlimited` in `BuyExecution`?

When should I use a certain amount? Because I found that people always use `Unlimited`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you will have to provide some funds into the holding register using an instruction like `WithdrawAsset` or `ClaimAsset`, so buying execution assumes that you have something in the holding register to buy with.

At the beginning of execution, the executor will [weigh the entire message](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/2b0d832/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L83), given what it knows about the weight of each `Instruction` in the array (some instructions, like `Transact`, need to be told a max weight).

Now that it knows the weight, it can check if it [`should_execute`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/2b0d832/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L112). The key here is how it constructs the `BuyExecution` instruction:

```rust
match i {
    BuyExecution { weight_limit: Limited(ref mut weight), .. } if *weight >= max_weight => {
        *weight = max_weight;
        Ok(())
    },
    BuyExecution { ref mut weight_limit, .. } if weight_limit == &Unlimited => {
        *weight_limit = Limited(max_weight);
        Ok(())
    },
    _ => Err(()),
}
```

If the weight is `Unlimited`, it will just try to use whatever funds are in the holding register to buy enough weight to execute the instructions. By putting in `Limited(weight)`, you are basically saying "I'm only willing to buy this much weight, and if the message comes out to be heavier, then don't execute it."

Of course, even with `Unlimited`, it can still fail. Depending on the weight to fee rate, you may not have provided enough funds in the holding register, in which case you'll get a `TooExpensive` error.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a certain amount like `WeightLimit::Limited(5000000000)`, it means the upper limit of weight you are willing to pay for XCM, if the actual need over than this amount, the XCM will not be executed.

Let's take a look at the code:

1. Before XCM is executed, the required weight will be calculated by your `weigher`(config in `XcmCExecutorConfig`)  https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.26/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L84

```
let xcm_weight = match Config::Weigher::weight(&mut message)
```

2. Then enter the barrier, your `BuyExecution` instruction will be modified. https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.26/xcm/xcm-builder/src/barriers.rs#L80

```
        match i {
            BuyExecution { weight_limit: Limited(ref mut weight), .. } if *weight >= max_weight => {
                *weight = max_weight;
                Ok(())
            },
            BuyExecution { ref mut weight_limit, .. } if weight_limit == &Unlimited => {
                *weight_limit = Limited(max_weight);
                Ok(())
            },
            _ => Err(()),
        }
```

As you can see, if you use `Unlimited` or a certain weight lager than the required weight, it will be replaced by the weight caculated in the first step.

But if you use a certain weight smaller than the required weight, it will be error and blocked by the barrier.